# mysql: IF 'some columns value' is DISTINCT THEN flip boolean value

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement, distinct

It seems that I'm asking a simple question but I haven't been able to find an answer that works for me. I hope you can help!

I'm writing a php script that takes some form data from an html-file `(name, artist, song)` and put it into a table with the columns `(name, artist, song, queue, newcomer)`. Now, the column `newcomer` is a boolean; and I want this boolean value to change from the default of false or 0, to true, or 1, if the name value of the incoming form data is unique.

This is my try:

```
$newcomer = mysql_query(
                'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tbl_queue) 
                 THEN UPDATE tbl_queue newcomer=1'
            );
```

but obviously, it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance!!

---

Hi and thanks for the answer! HOwever it still doesn't work for me =( 
THis is the code from the php:

$newcomer = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_queue SET newcomer=1 WHERE name='" . $_POST[name] . "' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tbl_queue WHERE name='" . $_POST[name] . "')" );

Comment: Just an FYI: Using $_POST directly in your sql query would make your php script vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be tempted to do your initial insert like this:-

```
INSERT INTO tbl_queue (name, artist, song, queue, newcomer)
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, a.artist, a.song, a.queue, CASE WHEN b.newcomer IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as newcomer
FROM (SELECT '$name' AS name, '$artist' AS artist, '$song' AS song, '$queue' AS queue) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_queue b
ON a.name = b.name
```

Have a dummy select of the values you want to insert, and left join that against the existing table based on name, using a CASE statement to check if a matching row was found or not.

EDIT - Below is some php showing the var assignments and escaping the values. I have used mysql_ functions here as you have in your original post, but really should be using mysqli_ functions to future proof things.

```
<?php

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$artist = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['artist']);
$song = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['song']);
$fcfs_queue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fcfs_queue']);

$sql = ("INSERT INTO tbl_queue (name, artist, song, fcfs_queue, newcomer)
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, a.artist, a.song, a.fcfs_queue, CASE WHEN b.newcomer IS NULL  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as newcomer
FROM (SELECT '$name' AS name, '$artist' AS artist, '$song' AS song, '$fcfs_queue' AS  fcfs_queue) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_queue b
ON a.name = b.name");


if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "success";


?>
```

Comment: Ok, I could try this but I am a newbie :) And I don't get what a. and b. is?

Comment: a and b are aliases. a. is an alias name for the subselect while b. is an alias name for the table tbl_queue.

Comment: tried to comment on this but my answer didn't fit within the limits, so answering my own question instead with code.

Answer (score 1):

```
"UPDATE tbl_queue SET newcomer=1
    WHERE   name = '" . $name_variable . "' AND
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT name
                            FROM tbl_queue
                            WHERE name='" . $name_variable . "')"
```

Is that what you are trying to do? Obviously replace $name_variable with the correct variable.

**Edit:** reformatted SQL

Comment: I have answered this as a reply to the thread but it was deleted; now it's in the original post as an edit. I tried your solution but unfortunately it didn't work. Sadly, because this is the only answer I really understand =))

Comment: It returns "Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /customers/b/6/d/coriantes.com/httpd.www/insert_records.php on line 34 Error:"


Code:

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_queue SET newcomer=1 WHERE name='" . $_POST[name] . "' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tbl_queue WHERE name='" . $_POST[name] . "')"
);

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this to be a comment to Kickstart but it doesn't fit within the limits of a comment, so.. i hope it's ok I answer here?

Thank you! However that didn't work either...
It returns this error:
Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource (regarding this row:   die('Error: ' . mysql_error($sql));   in the if statement)

My code is:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO tbl_queue (name, artist, song, fcfs_queue, newcomer)
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, a.artist, a.song, a.fcfs_queue, CASE WHEN b.newcomer IS NULL  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as newcomer
FROM SELECT '$name' AS name, '$artist' AS artist, '$song' AS song, '$fcfs_queue' AS  fcfs_queue) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_queue b
ON a.name = b.name");


if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($sql));
  }
echo "success";
```

Comment: You have a bracket missing in the SQL. Add an open bracket between FROM and SELECT (ie FROM (SELECT '$name' AS name )

Comment: Ohhh how embarrassing :o

Changed it. However still no luck =(
Still the same error message. Code:
   $sql = ("INSERT INTO tbl_queue (name, artist, song, fcfs_queue,  newcomer)
   SELECT DISTINCT a.name, a.artist, a.song, a.fcfs_queue, CASE WHEN b.newcomer IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as newcomer
   FROM SELECT ('$name' AS name, '$artist' AS artist, '$song' AS song, '$fcfs_queue' AS fcfs_queue) a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_queue b
   ON a.name = b.name");

Comment: Could the problem be that I use MySQL version 3.x..?

Comment: You have added the bracket in the wrong place. You have added it after the SELECT . It needs to be after the FROM and before the SELECT. The missing bracket wasn't your fault, it is something I made a mess of with my original code. Sorry. I will fix mine now

Comment: Ah!! Now we have progress! It adds the row to the queue! However it doesn't add the form content, it just switches the boolean to 1. So my form values (name, artist, song) aren't inserted into the table =(

Comment: You need to assign the form fields into the vars used in the INSERT, but sanitise them first (if you don't you leave yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks). For example $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

Comment: They are assigned? The html form values are now:
<form action="insert_records.php" method="post">
name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
artist: <input type="text" name="artist"><br><br>
song: <input type="text" name="song"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Request!" onclick="return confirmSubmit();">
</form>

Comment: and yes, "sanitazing" them is the next thing to deal with on my to-do-list. THanks for the help there too, I will do that once I get this thing working.

Comment: They need to be assigned. Copied from the form fields (ie, $_POST['name']) into the variable in the INSERT statement (ie, $name). You could use the form field directly but using a variable makes it easier to put into the SQL, and provides an obvious opportunity to check the values and sanitise it. I will edit my solution to make things obvious.

Comment: Oh, you mean to write the $ sign in the html form name field? like this:  <input type="text" name="$name"> ?

Comment: Or maybe that I need to add VALUES $_POST['name'] .. and so on, in the INSERT clause? So that the first row becomes...
$sql = ("INSERT INTO tbl_queue (name, artist, song, fcfs_queue, newcomer VALUES $_POST['name'] , $_POST['artist'] , $_POST['song'])?

Comment: No. The form field is returned to the script in an array, in this case the $_POST array. The HTML name of the form field is used as the subscript to that array. My suggestion is that in your PHP script you take the field in the $_POST array, perform mysql_real_escape_string on it and assign the result of that to a php variable (ie, something starting with $).

Comment: I am really sorry that I am such a slow learner, thanks for bearing with me. I'm trying to understand this; I don't get the array-thing really - I have three form fields with the names "name" "artist" and "song". so, if I am to take these field names I get three $_POST's, right? In code, it would be: INSERT INTO tbl_queue (name, artist, song VALUES '$_POST[name]' , '$_POST[artist]' , '$_POST[song]') 
However I've tried this both with and without the two remaining columns but it still gives me the "Expects parameter to be..." error. Again, sorry for being so slow..

Comment: Ah, I just read your last post! Hang on, I'll try to read and try it!

Comment: An array is one variable containing lots of values. So in php you might have $a = array(0=>"something", 1=>"otherthing"); That sets up a variable called $a which is an array. $a[0] contains "something" and $a[1] contains "otherthing". The 0 and 1 here are indexes. The same applies to form fields which are put into an array for you (normally the $_POST array), and the field names on the form are used as the indexes to this array. Hence $_POST['artist'] contains the value of the artist field from the form.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! It works now!! :) 
An array I do know ( in theory) what it is, but I didn't understand where in my code three different values ended up in one array; but now with your latest explanation I think I do! However I still think I should have been able to write VALUES '$_POST[name]' , '$_POST[artist]' , '$_POST[song]' because then I address each index(?) in the $_POST array that I'm inserting to. Again MUCH THANKS!! I am so happy.

Comment: You should have been able to, but you make no mention of the 4th (fcfs_queue) column. Likely that those values had been put into the SQL OK, but the SQL had failed for some other reason. Sanitising / escapeing the data is important. For example if name had a quote in it (') then without escaping the data your SQL would fail. And there are FAR more dangerous things people could enter in the field to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a trigger for that, as it is a "fixed" requirement for your table:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `newComerCheck`//
CREATE TRIGGER `newComerCheck` BEFORE INSERT ON `songs`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE c integer;
    SELECT COUNT(name) FROM `songs` WHERE `name`=NEW.name INTO c;

    IF (c >= 1) THEN
      SET NEW.newcomer=0;
    ELSE 
      SET NEW.newcomer=1;
    END IF;
  END
//
```

See fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e73b5/1

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this if Kickstart's solution doesn't work out (now that I'm trying that).

Comment: @Kei don't forget to set the delimiter to // when adding the trigger. (`DELIMITER //`) Otherwhise you'll get Syntax errors.

Comment: Ok. Thanx! I'm not sure what a delimiter is though, is it what calls the trigger? The newComerCheck on lines 1 and 2?

Comment: The Delimiter is just the line Seperater. Normaly `;` is used, but as the Trigger ITSELF is containing `;`s you need to tell mysql, that the WHOLE trigger is one statement. This is done by using another delimiter OUTSIDE of the trigger query. Note the `//`s after the Drop and the complete trigger statement. MYSQL now sees "Two statements", where the second one is made of many statements, but seperated by `;`.

Comment: @Kei On a side node: A Trigger needs to be defined ONCE (using your favourite Database-Management-Tool). The Table then will keep that trigger until the table itself is dropped, or the Trigger is dropped.

Comment: A delimiter is what is used to define the end of the statement. Default is the semi colon, hence if you do not change the default your trigger statement becomes about ~1 line long and invalid. Hence you change the delimiter to something that won't be used in the code so MySQL realises that what has been entered is one statement to be added as a new trigger.